# InstallLocation Doesn't Seem To Work

Tags: android, location, installation, sd-card

I am messing with the installLocation attribute in the Manifest of my test app, but it doesn't seem to want to work.  I have tried both "auto" and "preferExternal", and in both cases it seems to still be acting as though I don't have it set at all.

It does this on both my 2.3.3 Droid X, as well as the emulator.  I've searched quite a bit, and it seems that most people have problems with this because of their sdk version settings.  My minSDK is set to 4 and my targetSDK is set to 9, so that should be fine.

The only thing I can think of that *may* be the cause is that I still have the "debuggable" attribute set, and that may have some kind of adverse effect on it?  I also thought it may be possible that it isn't allowing it to install to the SD card because it was mounted while connected to my PC, but it never would allow me to "Move to SD Card", even after being disconnected.

This is something I would really like to have a good handle on for future apps, so any suggestions on how to get it working would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the minsdk set to 8

More details here [Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/installlocation.html)